# Spring MVC Thymeleaf absolute view ID `/view` behaves inconsistently

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I had a simple Spring MVC application with Thymeleaf. I had a controller mapped to `/foo/` and it would delegate to a view `/bar/view` using redirect, so its `POST` method would return `redirect:/bar/view`. This worked fine in my IDE, from a JAR file, and from a Docker container.

I did some refactoring and remapped the controller to `/view`. Then I moved my view implementation from `templates/foo/view.html` to `templates/view.html`. And instead of sending back `redirect:/bar/view`, I sent back `/view`. This continued to work fine in my IDE (Eclipse EE 2023-03 on Windows) with Spring DevTools installed.

However it would fail running from the JAR, saying that it could not find `/view`. I double-checked everything, and finally just discovered that it will now only work from a JAR file if I return `view` for the view, and not `/view`.

Can someone tell me why this inconsistency exists, and point me to some documentation that covers this? Why can't I return `/view` as a view ID? But why does returning `/view` work in my IDE, but not using `java -jar …`? And finally, why does `redirect:/bar/view` work with an absolute view path, but not `/view`? I'm not arguing which way is better; I'm just wondering why the behavior is inconsistent, and wanting to know where this is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good to start with how Spring Boot resolves the view names.

When you return a view with a leading slash `/view` then Spring treats it as an **absolute path** and looks for the view in the **root directory of your app**.

If you are using view without a leading slash `view` then Spring treats it as a **relative path** and looks for the view **from the current directory**.

**Why then IDE works?**

Because IDE sets the working directory to the root of your project.

**Why then JAR doesn't work?**

It's because JAR sets the working directory to the directory where the JAR file contains.

**Why does `redirect:/bar/view` work?**

Redirect make a new request to the server, and then resolves the view name using the same rules as before.

It's good to use relative paths to prevent ambiguities.

Some information you can find [Spring. Views and resolving them](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s05.html)

Comment: RAI, your answer is excellent. You answered precisely my questions and gave me a reference for follow up. I'm going to assign a bounty to thank you for your time and attention to detail.

Comment: "If you are using view without a leading slash `view` then Spring treats it as a `relative path` and looks for the view **from the current directory**." From the current directory of the URL? @RAI this part is still a little confusing. If I have a controller mapped to `/foo/bar` and the view is stored in `…/templates/foo/view`, then returning `view` as the view doesn't work, even though it's at the same directory level as `/foo/bar` in the URL path. I have to return `foo/view` and just remember that this is apparently relative to the root of my context, not of the "current directory".